# Move an object between two points in a loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a script where an object moves between two points (A) and (B) in a loop. But the point (A) also continuously changes its `transform.position()`. How can I make the object move in loop while reading new point (A) values?

```
public float speed = 0.1f;
public Transform PointA;
public Transform PointB;
private Vector3 origin;
private bool backToOrigin;
private bool GoForIt = true;
public float BeginTime = 0;
public int NumberOfCounts = 1000;
private float Counter = 0;

public void Start()
{
    transform.position = PointA.transform.position;
    origin = transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    if (GoForIt == true && Counter < NumberOfCounts)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, backToOrigin ? origin : PointB.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position == PointB.transform.position || transform.position == origin)
        {
            backToOrigin = !backToOrigin;
            Counter+=0.5f;
        }
    }

    if(Counter>=NumberOfCounts)
    {
        GoForIt = false;   
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell what you want

Comment: @AhmedAli To move my object between two points while one point's transform values continuously changes.

Comment: so when the second points changes it's position then the object will not approach it.

Comment: @AhmedAli. Lets say the object moves from Point A to Point B, during this time the Point A changes its position. Now, while returning from Point B, the object should move towards the changing point A position.

Comment: Is this as simple as replacing `origin` with `PointA.transform.position` in `Update()`? It seems that you are saving the fixed point `origin`, but would rather it not be fixed.

Comment: @Rhaokiel Thank you! I had not noticed that the origin was not changing the value of pointA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should simply not use `origin` at all but rather

```
...

transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, backToOrigin ? PointA.transform.position: PointB.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

if (transform.position == PointB.transform.position || transform.position == PointA.transform.position)
{
    ...
```

---

#### If point A didn't move:

Probably exactly the use case of [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

> Linearly interpolates between two points.

where the third parameter `factor` is a value between `0` and `1`

combined with [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html)

> The returned value will move back and forth between 0 and length.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform PointA;
    public Transform PointB;

    void Update()
    {
        // Set the position to loop between PointA and PointB
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(PointA, PointB, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / speed, 1));
    }
}
```

---

Comment: The difference is `Lerp` will change the angle at which the object is moving towards PointB while PointA is moving. This is because `Lerp` doesn't move towards, but rather sets an absolute position. Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can lerp between any two points. 
Ex:

```
PointA, PointB

transform.position=Vector3.Lerp(A,B,timeFloat)
if(magnitude(CurrentPositionVector-Vector3A)<0.1)
{
point A = new vector3(x,y,z) // new point coordinates
}
```

What it does is that:
1. You are lerping from point A to B,
2. When the object's position reaches really close to the destination point, the destination is changed to  a new point.
3. You can repeat it as many times as you want.